# How to use like and in together?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

How to use like and in together ?

```
SELECT a FROM A WHERE a LIKE (SELECT b FROM B WHERE c='india');
```

where column a and b are not equal but b only contains first three digits of a as shown below 
a=145xxxxxx;
b=145;

any clue? how to achieve it?

Comment: Is 'b' only ever going to be three numbers or can it be any amount of numbers?

Comment: Its going to be only three numbers of 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.a 
FROM A 
inner join B on A.a like concat(B.b,'%')
             and B.c = 'india'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a FROM A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE c='india' AND A.a LIKE CONCAT(B.b,'%') );
```